# Is there a way to debug two iOS devices on the same Mac?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, cloudkit, cksubscription

I guess it is not possible from the same Xcode, but via opening Xcode multiple times? Or any other trick? I am testing CKSubscription and CloudKit communication between them.

Comment: You can easily start an iOS app on two device connected to your mac within the same Xcode. Just selected the device choose run and after it it running select the second device and hit run again (do not press stop) and both the devices are new attached to the debugger.

Comment: Of course it's possible, on the xcode's debug area you can change the device you want to check the console. Just click on the top right of the debug area where you can see your app icon, app name and device name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just run the app from the xcode on multiple devices that are connected.
Just select in run Area the other iphone and click run.

So both should give you output to the console.

Answer (score 3):

For Xcode 9

Connect both the devices to your mac.

Then run to the first device, you can debug and can see the logs now.

Now select the second device that you have connected to the mac and open a new tab in xcode by pressing cmd + T, then run.

Now you will be having the logs of that device in the second tab & the previous device in the first tab.

Comment: It doesn't work for XCode 12.4

new tab or new window doesn't matter. If you choose second iphone on the other hand, on the first screen "second iphone" appears immediately.